Why do the :focus state properties override the :active ones in my CSS?
I get that the solution is to place the :focus selector and properties before the :active ones but I don't get why, especially considering that focus and active are different states, even if clicking and activating an element eventually brings it to a focus state
here's the code
a:hover {
    color: lightpink;
    text-decoration: overline;
}

a:active {
    color: #222;
    font-weight: 700;
}

a:focus {
    color: lightpink;
    text-decoration: overline;
}


Expected the active properties to show for a brief moment when the link was clicked as opposed to not working at all

Basically, elements can have multiple states at once, just like they can have multiple classes. The CSS is applied in order of specificity. A rule for a p is applied to every p, then p.class is applied to all p with the class, overwritting properties if there are overlaps. This is as simple as that. Now when a specificity is exactly the same, the order used is the order of appearance in the file.

https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/517d35f0c50c3d60c9003502#:~:text=The%20recommended%20order%20is%20link,both%20visited%20and%20unvisited%20links.
